# Gradle: version conflict

Tags: java, android, gradle

`Gradle` выдает такую ошибку:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

Как ее правильно исправить? Как сделать айпдейт  `google-services plugin` или обновить версию `com.google.android.gms`?

Мой app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.iryna.firebaseexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    // Firebase Authentication
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'

    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Выкладываю `root build.gradle:`

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: думаю и то и другое не помешает. Вообще лучше всего использовать последние стабильные версии библиотек всегда.

Comment: @pavlofff Так а как их обновить?

Comment: думаю, что в SDK manager, так как в конфигах gradle все вроде на месте

Comment: @pavlofff я не нашла в SDK Manager ничего похожего

Comment: в секции *Extras* - Google Play services и Google Repository

Comment: Попробуйте build-clean и рестарт студии/компа

Comment: @ЮрийСПб помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно что-то где-то в студии/проекте поломалось и помочь может `build-clean` + рестарт студии/компа